# Flutter log gets old or other files from another project

Tags: flutter

After Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...  Flutter get errors from another flutter projects e.g E/flutter ( 6549): #2      NewsBloc.fetchN (package:flutter_user_me/bloc/fetch_data_bloc.dart:21:27)

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46815

Work around from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46815#issuecomment-571678229 
As a work around, if you run `adb logcat -c` before launching your app, it will clear out old messages. 
Be warned that it also clears previous log messages in general